# qt app support problem on nokia e series

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, nokia, qt-mobility

I have developed a qt app with which uses mobility and phonon.

Qt version is 4.6.3 and Mobility is 1.0.2

Now when i install the smart-installer package on a s60v5 device, It installs correctly and runs also well.
But when I try to install it on a E series phone like E63 i gets installed. But when tried to run it, i get a message 'feature not supported' and app doesn't start at all.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at section "Querying Backends for Support" .
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/phonon-overview.html
 Phonon and Phonon backends are not recommended on Symbian. Use the multimedia framework in QtMobility.

Comment: phonon backend is suppported on s60v3 using MMF.Then what could be the issue? http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/platform-notes-symbian.html